# How to assign php file(template) to several pages with same prefix page name/slug

Tags: functions, pages, slug

Can I assign WP php file (specific template) to several pages with same prefix name/slug using (`if is_page(){}`) ?

If it's possible it could be useful.
Is there a php function to do like css selector : `[class*="activity-"]`
for example ??: `if(is_page('[activity-]')){ include "activity.php"; }`

the goal is to not repeat 4 times the same function :
`if(is_page('activity-sport')){ include "activity.php"; }`

`activity.php` assign to :

- `website/activity-sport`
- `website/activity-culture`
- `website/activity-charity`
- `website/activity-work`

Comment: are you aware of page templates or template parts?

Comment: Yes, I know perfectly. 
But I use wordpress only for content, I use php file to create new templates . I can't use "page attributes" and "model" in wp right side menu!

Precisely I want to use a template for several pages. But I will use many different templates by major categories: activities, news, businesses, companies, etc.

The layout of the content and the php queries will not be the same. I prefer to have several php pages (templates) to distinguish each major category and not repeat unnecessary queries.
maybe I'll use subdomains later.

Comment: I will still test the page template using model, but I think I would still be limited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this?

For PHP 8 (faster)

```
if ( str_contains( get_post_field( 'post_name' ), 'activity') ) { 
    get_template_part( 'activity' );
}
```

For older versions of PHP

```
if ( strpos(get_post_field( 'post_name' ), 'activity') !== false ) { 
    get_template_part( 'activity' );
}
```

Comment: thank you so much